# If there exists a function $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(y)=f(c)+(y-c)g(y)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, show that $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in(a,b)$. If there exists a function $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(c)+(x-c)g(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, show that $f$ is differentiable at $c$. In this case $f'(c)=g(c)$.

My attempt:

Assume $x\in(a,b)$ and $x\neq c$, $f(x)=f(c)+(x-c)g(x) \Longrightarrow g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$. Now we need to prove $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ exists and equals to $g(c)$, I'm stuck here. I think I need to prove $g$ is continuous at $c$ but I don't know how to do.

Comment: You probably need continuity of g. Otherwise take $f(x)=|x| , x \in (-1,1)$ and see that $f(x)=f(0)+x g(x)$where $g(x)=sign(x)$ which is not continuous.

Comment: For an arbitrary $g$ you can't even conclude that $f$ is continuous at $c$. The proper theorem involves additional hypothesis that $g$ is continuous at $c$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is wrong. $g$ **always** exists, whether or not $f$ is differentiable:$g(x)=\frac {f(x)-f(c)} {x-c}$ for $x \neq c$ and $g(c)$ arbitrary. When $g$ is continuous at $c$ you already know the answer. For a specific counter-example take $f(x)=|x-c|$ and define $g$ as above.

Answer (score 1):

The said assertion is not true. $f$ need not be differentiable. Consider, for example $g:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined as
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac 1{x^2}; x\ne0\\0; x=0\end{cases}$$

Choosing $c=0$, you may note here that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.